# Increase the editor width or viewable area in Typora

Tags: editor, markdown

When writing in the Typora, the viewable width (editor width) is limited.

[image]

How could I enlarge from A to B?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change CSS file of the theme you are using. Go to **`File > Preference`** or press **`Ctrl+Comma`**. In **`Themes`** click **`Open Theme Folder`**.

[image: screenshot]

Open the CSS file of your theme. For example I'm using *Github* theme.

[image]

So I'm opening **`github.css`** file. In CSS file go to `#write` (write id). Here change the value of `max-width`.

[image]

Default value of `max-width` in this theme is 860px. You can increase this to whatever you want. For example:

```
max-width: 1200px;
```

In some themes, you may also find `max-width` in `em` instead of `px`. For example:

```
max-width: 40em;
```

Increase this value to whatever width you prefer.

In case you want the editor to be of full width, remove this `max-width` property entirely.

Answer (score 5):

### Typora and responsible width

For the record, you can edit the file as follow.

- Look at the folders where is the CSS (as indicated by itsmysterybox)
- Find the .css file and copy it with a new file. For example github2.css
- Also, copy the folder related with the .css that you copied and rename it with the same name, for example, github2\
- Find the next lines:

  @media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  #write {
  max-width: 1024px;
  }
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 1800px) {
  #write {
  max-width: 1200px;
  }
  }

And delete it.

- Find the next line

  #write {
  max-width: 860px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  }

And edit the line **max-width: 860px;**  to **max-width: 95%;**

- Restart the application and select the new theme (see image)

### Why 95% instead of 100%?

We are giving it some space for the scroll bar. However, and apparently, 100% also works and it doesn't break any visualization.

### Why we need to copy the .css and the folder instead of editing an existing one?

Because updates of the program could (and most likely will) replace it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's two [support pages](https://support.typora.io/Width-of-Writing-Area/) [on Typora's website](https://support.typora.io/Add-Custom-CSS/) that address this. The main difference between @itsmysterybox's answer is that you create a `base.user.css` file in the themes folder, and add the below snippet with whatever value you prefer. Doing it this way means that it will apply to all themes.

```
#write {
  max-width: 1800px; /*adjust writing area position*/
}
```

If you want to adjust the width of source code mode you can use:

```
#typora-source .CodeMirror-lines {
  max-width: auto; /*or 1000px*/
}
```